# "libvir" not found in "sudo apt install libvir"

Tags: apt, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I want to install Qemu on ubuntu 22.04 following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyLNpPY-Je0&ab_channel=Abstractprogrammer)

However, when I enter `sudo apt install libvir` I get

```
E: Unable to locate package libvir
```

Does anyone know whats wrong with my system? (I also used `sudo apt install libvirt` instead of `libvir` but the same outcome). Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The package name is [`libvirt-daemon`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/libvirt-daemon).

```
sudo apt install libvirt-daemon
```